Can't pass generic props to function component (Type is not assignable to type IntrinsicAttributes & P)
I have the following function:
export default function Hidable<P>(Component: React.FC<P>) {
  return function Wrapped(props: P & { hidden: boolean }) {
    const { hidden, ...rest } = props;

    return hidden ? null : <Component {...rest} />;
  };
}

However, I'm receiving the following error:

The weird thing is that, every other function that uses this one has the typing working perfectly:


The following works:
export default function Hidable<P>(Component: React.FC<P>) {
  return function Wrapped(props: P & { hidden: boolean }) {
    return props.hidden ? null : <Component {...props} />;
  };
}

However, what I'm trying to achieve is having the behavior of not displaying the HTML when the hidden prop is specified, but the Component doesn't need to receive the prop when being passed to the Hidable function.
Anything that I change, breaks the other functions. Any idea how to fix this or configure typing properly?
